# Calling a URL in non-blocking manner on a webpage

Tags: html, css, asynchronous

### Story time

I have a purchased/rented typeface whose license asks me to query a unique counter on their domain every time the typeface is shown. Sadly, their suggestion is to call it in the CSS file with `import`, which blocks rendering for the duration of the call. It is also weird since according to the license they wish to track individual page views yet if the CSS file in question is cached, won't that prevent the import from being called again until cache clears?

In any case, I removed the `import` call, but then began to ponder what exactly should I replace it with. What tag would give me a non-blocking call that would work universally across browsers and irregardless of disabled features? A link with `rel=prefetch`? HTML5, it didn't work in IE7 when I tested it. And it would also feel awkward since it implies the resource should be cached yet the response contains a `No-Cache` directive. A script tag with `defer` and `async` attributes at the end of the page? Maybe, but what if someone has disabled scripting? I could add a `noscript` tag and then an image tag inside it as a fallback. But! Will the image display as broken for some browsers since the image contents are an empty string? And what if someone has scripting AND images disabled? Oh no! World must be a pretty bleak place for them, I must admit. Oh, oh! What about `embed/object`? Now that's just wrong, stop touching me funny.

I ended up going with just a plain image tag for now, but what would be the magical combination that would cover the widest range of edge cases? I could add the `script` tag for example to support those without image loading on.

My intrigue here is purely scientifical so I'm not really looking for alternative typeface providers or to discuss how unlikely previously described situations are. Also, why they provide me with the actual font file to serve from my own server and then trust me to call the counter honestly is beyond me.

### Code

Let's imagine my unique font counter is located at http://font.foo/bar and the font.foo server is acting slow.

---

*Starting point*

```
// fonts.css
@import url('font.foo/bar')
@font-face { ... }

// index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
```

---

*Separate link tag*

```
// Problem: Blocks rendering
// index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font.foo/bar">
```

---

*rel=prefetch*

```
// Problem: Won't load in IE7, semantically awkward
// index.html
<link rel="prefetch" href="font.foo/bar">
```

---

*Deferred async script load*

```
// Problem: Won't work when user has disabled scripting
// index.html
    <script src="font.foo/bar" async defer>
</body>
```

---

*Script tag with added image fallback*

```
// Problem: Won't work when user has disabled scripting AND images
// index.html
    <script src="font.foo/bar" async defer>
    <noscript><img src="font.foo/bar" alt=""></noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), why didn't it work? Post some code.

Comment: Donesies! Added code snippets and problems with each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mix it this way?
You have the script options and keep using a link element instead of an img

```
    <script src="font.foo/bar" async defer>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="font.foo/bar"></noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: `<link>` is not valid within `<body>`

Comment: Not with rel anyway. With itemprop attribute yes, but that's HTML5 so that wouldn't work in older browsers, and it's semantically wrong anyway.

Comment: You didn't state that you were searching for semantic purity, and old (and current) browsers will load a stylesheet from wherever you tell them, no matter what the specs say.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to get back to you but I think I went with a CSS hidden image at the end. The link tag would be a nice option too in this case if browsers indeed do all load it.